# Getting relative url of folder (using python shareplum library)

Tags: python, sharepoint, shareplum

I have successfully connected to Sharepoint via python shareplum library and I am able to manipulate with contents as I want. However, I am unable to find way to delete any folder I give it. Shareplum keeps throwing at me that "You must pass the relative folder url to delete a folder".

I am using available method as from Shareplum documentation (.delete_folder(relative_url))
[image]

Could someone please help how to either get the relative path of any folder or how do I modify my code to make this work?

For testing purposes, I have created empty folder 'deleteme' and my code is set up in trying to delete it.

```
from shareplum import Site
from shareplum import Office365
from shareplum.site import Version

authcookie = Office365(r'https://mysite.sharepoint.com', username='my.email@domain.com', password='mypass').GetCookies()

site = Site(r'https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/mysitelocation/',version=Version.v365, authcookie=authcookie)

site.Folder('Shared Documents').delete_folder('deleteme')
```

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Just managed to work this one out by adding:

```
folder = site.Folder('Shared Documents/General/deleteFolder/')

folder.delete_folder(folder.folder_name)
```